# Android Formatter not giving correct time

Tags: android, android-timepicker

so I have this code in Android

```
            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(millisUntilFinished);
            textView.setText(formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

here is how I am passing the values to this method, where the hours and minutes strings are "8" and "30" for example

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            String s = ApplicationPreferences.getWakeUp(ActivityStage1.this);
            String[] separated = s.split("\\:");
            String hours = separated[0];
            String minutes = separated[1];
            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(hours));
            c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(minutes));
            c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            long timeUntilStageTwo = (c.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis());
            startStageTwoTimer(timeUntilStageTwo);
```

So the value in the long millisUntilFinished is something like 58441666, which is around 16 hours and 20 min, but for some reason the time it shows at the end in the text view is with 3 hours more, I even tried with different locales passed to SimpleDateFormat, and still the same, why is that happening?

Comment: Try using Locale.US. Very small chance it will work but it's good practice to use explicit Locales anyway

Comment: the thing is I am setting the Locale at first run of the app, so its either "en" or "es", and with both works the same

Comment: Tried using Date instead of Calendar?

Comment: see my updated question please, seems like the milliseconds passed to the second method are wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your `Calendar c` is in your local UTC+3 timezone while the system clock runs at UTC. Hence the difference of 3 hours.

You can use [`setTimeZone()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone)) to set an explicit timezone on your calendar before computing its millisecond value.

If you prefer to do the computations yourself, you can get the user's timezone with `TimeZone.getDefault()` and then use `getOffset(time)` to get the millisecond offset at specified UTC time.

Comment: so how do I know which time zone the user is in? I only have a Locale object being set up at launch

Comment: where do I use this getOffset method, right after getDefault it gives me error

Comment: that still gives me problems, I need just a simple converter to show me milliseconds in hours and minutes, not some complicated classes like Calendar or Date that get affected by time zone